# How to update mulltiple "keys" of a jsonb column in PostgresSQL using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, jsonb

Trying to update multiple "keys" of a `jsonb` column in PostgresSQL using Laravel Eloquent and it throws following exception

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  multiple assignments to same column "options" (SQL: update "specs" set "options" = jsonb_set("options"::jsonb, '{"php"}', "8.1.0"), "options" = jsonb_set("options"::jsonb, '{"laravel"}', "master"), "options" = jsonb_set("options"::jsonb, '{"db"}', "14"), where "id" = 1)
```

**Schema**

```php
Schema::create('specs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->jsonb('options')->nullable();
});
```

The values of `options` columns will have multiple keys for example: `php`, `laravel`, `db`

```json
{"php": "7.0.8", "laravel": "8.47.0", "db": "postgres 13.3"}
```

I am trying to update below values, is there any other way to generate the "correct" SQL query

```php
$values = [
   "options->php" => "8.1.0",
   "options->laravel" => "master",
   "options->db" => "14",
];
Specs::where('id', 1)->update($values);
```

The correct SQL query should be either of following

```sql
-- Recursive
update "specs"
set "options" = jsonb_set(
        jsonb_set(
            jsonb_set(
                "options" :: jsonb,
                '{"db"}',
                "14"
            ),
            '{"laravel"}',
            "master"
        ),
        '{"php"}',
        "8.1.0"
    ),
where "id" = 1;

-- Merge
update "specs"
set "options" = options || '{"php": "8.1.0", "laravel": "master", "db": "14"}',
where "id" = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the records in the `jsonb` column, you can use the following:

```
$values = [
   "options" => [
       "php" => "8.1.0",
       "laravel" => "master",
       "db" => "14",
    ]
];

Specs::where('id', 1)->update($values);
```

Comment: This will remove other keys saved in the json from db. I only want to update a few keys and keep others untouched